# c++ simple clock subtraction command

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

long int minutes = 0;
int hours;

int main(){
    for (; minutes < 1000000;cout<<"Minutes: "<<hours<<"|Seconds: "<<minutes)
    {   
        ++minutes;
        Sleep(60000);
        if ( minutes == 60)
        {
            minutes - 60;// need help here!!!!!!
            hours++;
        }
        system("cls");}
        system("pause>nul");
        return 0;
    }
```

I just started to really learn c++ so i decided to make a simple counter which only counts minutes and hours but when the minutes hit 60 it keeps going. how do i make the counter subtract 60 also what would be the command to add a subtract any amount?

Comment: try :  minutes -= 60;

Comment: Turn on your warnings to at least get a definite conclusion that nothing is happening the first time you compile: *main.cpp:13:14: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]*
      `minutes - 60;// need help here!!!!!!`

Comment: Putting I/O as the third expression of the for loop is the prime example of obfuscation. Please don't do it. Also, your code formatting is quite a mess. Are you using old Dev-C++? If so, consider using other code editor, as it will make easier to achieve proper formatting, and in the long run, make easier for you to learn proper programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
minutes - 60;
```

statement has no effect, it does not store the result back to minutes.

Try:

```
minutes -= 60;
```

Comment: "minutes -= 60" is the same as saying "minutes = minutes - 60".

Comment: also egg thank you for telling me  that its like minutes -  minutes -60 it really helped me understand

Comment: @sickist: It's not. It's like `minutes = minutes - 60`.

Answer (score 0):

The line you point to in your question subtracts 60 from `minutes` but does not store it back into `minutes`. You could change it to `minutes -= 60` but this will cause an endless loop as `minutes` will never reach `1000000`. Since you are incrementing `minutes` at the start of every iteration you can use the modulus operator to determine if `hours` should be incremented.

```
if ( minutes % 60 == 0 )
{
    hours++;
}
```